# AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath return empty string for prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use unity5.5.4, drag a particle effect prefab to a UI prefab, do not hit apply, so the select button could select the original particle prefab in editor. I use script to findchild the effect prefab node, and then call `AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(go)` to get the effect path, but the return value is an empty string

this is the code I used to find the dragged particle effect prefab from UI prefab:

```
GameObject child = go.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject; 
if (child.tag == "particle") return child
```

Comment: Maybe you could try [PrefabUtility.GetPrefabAssetPathOfNearestInstanceRoot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.GetPrefabAssetPathOfNearestInstanceRoot.html)

Comment: @derHugo this API does not exist in unity5.x

Comment: than maybe you should consider upgrading to a newer version ... 5.x is quite a while ago now

Comment: @derHugo  Yes it is quite old,  but when the game is mature and online for a while, it is ofen not applicatable to upgrade to new version